# Actionbarsherlock not showing in android 2.2

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

im used this sliding menu in app https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu  action bar showing in api above 8 but action bar not showing in api 8 how to resolve this?tnx

Comment: What API level should I target in my manifest when using the library? Targetting API level 11 or newer is required as it will cause Android to automatically add the native action bar when run on newer devices. Since you will be compiling against new APIs but your app will likely be run on devices with older versions of Android extra care must be taken to either avoid using or properly check and call any methods that were introduced after your minimum SDK version. http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html

Comment: You can start to use AppCompat support library http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat

Comment: when use appcompat and sherlock lib my project give me error

Comment: Please provided the specific error (by updating your original post)

Comment: im solved it by change  MainActivity extends Activity to  MainActivity extends SherlockActivity